# Watch TV/recorded shows from my Comcast cable box on my Mac?

Tags: mac, tv, dvr

I've got a MacBook that's about three years old (it's the first generation that had a dual core CPU), running Leopard.  I've got a Comcast DVR/HD Cable box.  Is there something that I can install in between these devices that will let me watch TV from the Cable box on the Mac's display?

The Cable box is in one room, but my tush and the Mac are in the other (fixing code on another machine that can't be part of the equation).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is pretty much exactly what [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com) is made to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of hardware doing that... I used a PCI TV Tuner in my computer a long time ago and I really miss it!!!

You have a laptop, a mac also... so I would go with a USB TV Tuner. If you can run wires to your computer, that would be perfect for that kind of [USB TV Tuner](http://www.compusa.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4146199&CatId=4546)

Of course, this model is exepsive but you can find other for cheaper prices.

If you can't run wires (but I don't think you can brodcast wireless signal with your receiver), you can use this [USB Tv Tuner](http://www.7gadgets.com/2007/06/07/new-usb-tv-tuner-from-logitech/386)

Hope this will help you!

David